# floating div issues moving onto a new line

Tags: css

```
<div style="float: left"><a href="url" title="title">
<img src="/name.png" /></a></div>
<div style="text-align: right"><img src="/strip.png" /></div>
```

How do I get the /strip.png to move behind the /name.png when the page isn't wide enough for both on one line. At the moment the /strip.png goes to a new line. Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between "move underneath" and "goes to a new line?"

Comment: By move underneath I mean get pushed behind the first image.

Comment: In what browser? seems to work as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HLNTC/

Comment: Thanks but I need the cat on the right to go behind the cat on the left, not underneath it. I.e. it disappears behind the image on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this with absolute positioning if you want both div elements to occupy the same space (i.e. have one in front of the other).  You could potentially also do it with backgrounds and having the floated div be a child of the other div, but I think that would actually be more complicated.  In your simple example, changing `float: left` to `position: absolute` is enough.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HLNTC/1/

You may need to make the container of the two divs `position: relative` so the absolutely positioned div plays nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float: right your second div.

Comment: `float:left;` will work as well and make them both left aligned. I would only use `float:right;` if you stylistically want the image to be right aligned even on the new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
            justify-content: space-between;
            -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;" >
  <div>
    <a href="url" title="title"><img src="/name.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div><img src="/strip.png" /></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33XZ4/

Comment: thanks but I need the square on the right to disappear behind the square on the left when it is not wide enough for them both on the same line.